# How to disable logout confirmation in spring security using xml?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, logout

**I have updated Spring security from 4.x to 5.x. Now, I have this situation where Spring security asks user to confirm logout.** With message

*Are you sure you want to log out?*

below given image for the same.
[image]

**I want to get rid of this step. How to get rid of logout confirmation ?**

Objective : **I want to logout and redirect on page where I came from.**

The security.xml :

```xml
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.2.xsd">


    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <!-- isAnonymous() -->
        <intercept-url pattern="/**/add/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**/delete/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**/update/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="uzer64" password="{noop}123456" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
                <user name="admin" password="{noop}admin" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

Comment: That isn't a Spring Security screen, that only logs out on a post request. So that screen must be in your own application.

Comment: I know wha tyou want but it isn't a Spring Security thing it is  in  your own application code. So you need to fix you application not spring security configuration as that won't help.

Comment: @M.Deinum It is the screen provided by spring security, as explained in my answer.

Comment: And as I explained Spring Security doesn't have a logout confirmation screen/dialog. So trying to fix this in Spring Security isn't the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a CSRF feature to avoid logout request initiated by malicious javascript from another site.
Your request is `GET: /logout` and hence spring security wants to confirm it by user action such as click.

So to avoid it. Your logout request should be `POST` and contain valid `_csrf` token.

You can achieve it by using spring form tag with method post as given below

```html
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
...
<form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/logout" 
           method="post" modelAttribute="AnyModelAttributePassedFromController">
    <form:button value="submit"> Logout</form:button>
</form:form>
...
```

Or

```html
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
...
<form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/logout" 
           method="post" modelAttribute="_csrf">
    <form:button value="submit"> Logout</form:button>
</form:form>
...
```

Comment: Spring Security by default, only accepts POST logout requests. Everything else is ignored or at least not handled by the `LogoutFilter`.

Comment: I agree spring security by default handles only post logout, Even i agree for that comment which you mentioned fix is not for spring security configuration and fix should be done in your code. I explained why it will allow only POST request. I just wanted to mention you that `logout confirmation prompt box is provided by spring security but not from his code`.

Comment: No it isn't. Spring Security doesn't provide a logout confirmation prompt.

Comment: @M.Deinum It is. [Have a look at source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/ui/DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter.java)

Comment: Which has been added in 5.1 (apparently missed this in the changelog) as part of the newly/updated OAuth2 support. Then the solution is to either disable form-login (only applicable when not using it) or to make sure to use a POST (as mentioned in your answer). Learned something today about Spring Security again :).

Comment: This page show how to disable it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58195990/how-to-disable-logout-confirmation-in-spring-security-using-xml

Answer (score 6):

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"));
    }
```

It works for me.

Comment: Worked for me too, thanks...

Comment: Works for me using `Spring Boot 3.1.5` and `Keycloak 22.0.5`.

Answer (score -3):

You can try the below:-

```
    <logout
    logout-success-url="/anonymous.html"
    logout-url="/perform_logout" />
```

and you can mention the url where you want to redirect.You can also add 
    `delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"` for deleting cookies.